# Material UI v4 makeStyles exported from a single file doesn't retain the styles on refresh

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI v4, i'm exporting my styles from a single file,
But the styles won't work in other components
styles.js

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
    // textField component styles
    textFieldInput: {
      margin: theme.spacing(2),
      width: 250,
      minWidth: 250,
    },
    formControl: {
      margin: theme.spacing(2),
      minWidth: 120,
    },


})
export {useStyles}
```

In my component file

```
    ....
    const classes = useStyles(styles);

    return (
        <TextField
            className={classes.textFieldInput}
            label={label}
            placeholder={label}
            error={touched && invalid}
            helperText={touched && error}
            {...input}
            disabled={disabled || false}
            readOnly={readOnly || false}
            required={required || false}
            InputProps={{ readOnly, ...custom }}
            {...custom}
        />
    );
     ....
```

when i use it in my components
the styles will work on the first hot reload but after that the styles wont have any effect any ideas why? and how i can fix this

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Why is this happening?

If you have two CSS classes applied to the same element with the same degree of specificity, then the winner will be the CSS class that is defined last within the document (based on the order of the `<style>` elements in the `<head>`, **NOT** the order of the class name strings in the `class` attribute of the element being styled).

[This page](https://i1mwh.codesandbox.io/) is an example with two TextField elements that reproduces your problem. If you open the browser developer tools and look at the `<style>` elements, you will see that the styles from `makeStyles` come first followed by the styles from `TextField` (e.g. MuiFormControl). I've shown an abbreviated version below:

```
<style data-jss="" data-meta="makeStyles">
.makeStyles-textFieldInput-1 {
  margin: 32px;
  min-width: 250px;
}
</style>
<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiFormControl">
.MuiFormControl-root {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.MuiFormControl-marginNormal {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.MuiFormControl-marginDense {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.MuiFormControl-fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiTextField">

</style>
```

The `MuiFormControl-root` class is applied to the same element as the class specified via TextField's `className` property (e.g. the textFieldInput class from `makeStyles/useStyles`). Since the MuiFormControl `<style>` element occurs after the `makeStyles` `<style>` element, MuiFormControl's default styling for `margin` and `min-width` win over the custom styling specified by `makeStyles`.

The order of these `<style>` elements is controlled by the order in which `makeStyles` is called. For the default styling for a given Material-UI component, `makeStyles` is called at the point when the component is first imported.

For typical usage patterns, where `makeStyles` is called in the same JavaScript file that then calls `useStyles` and passes the classes to the Material-UI component, the order will always be what you would want because the imports of the Material-UI components will happen before the call to `makeStyles`.

When you move the call to `makeStyles` to a separate file and import the `useStyles` method that it returns, you introduce the possibility of importing `useStyles` **before** importing the Material-UI component (e.g. TextField in this case).

This is demonstrated in the code in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/makestyles-first-i1mwh

The reason it may work on the first hot reload is that the `makeStyles` `<style>` element is being removed and then added on to the end when you make changes. The Mui* style elements don't change so they remain where they are (which is before the new `makeStyles` style element until the page is reloaded).

You can't easily shoot yourself in the foot this way using the [Higher-order component API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) (i.e. `withStyles`) since `makeStyles` is called within `withStyles` so you will have always imported the component being wrapped by `withStyles` before passing it as a parameter.

---

### How can I fix this?

There are a few ways you could address this. One way is to just ensure that you import your `useStyles` function **after** importing Material-UI components such as `TextField`.

Change:

```
import { useStyles } from "./styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
```

to instead be:

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { useStyles } from "./styles";
```

This is demonstrated here: https://codesandbox.io/s/import-textfield-first-9qybd

This is fairly brittle however if you have styles for more than one type of component in `styles.js` and import `styles.js` from many files, since then for it to work reliably you are dependent on importing **all** of the Material-UI components that are styled by `styles.js` before the **first** place that you import `styles.js`.

---

Another way to address this is to export styled versions of the Material-UI components instead of exporting the `useStyles` function. Then you just import this customized component instead of the Material-UI component.

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiTextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: theme.spacing(4),
    minWidth: 250
  }
});

export const TextField = withStyles(styles)(MuiTextField);
```

This is demonstrated with a couple different syntax options here: https://codesandbox.io/s/import-styled-textfield-1ytxl

Comment: Big Thanks for the answer!
For some reason, importing the useStyles after the other components is not working, but may be its something wrong on my side, will try to debug based on the ideas you've shared!
Thanks for taking time and explaining !

Comment: You can also see this behavior if you have multiple copies of the styles package: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#i-have-several-instances-of-styles-on-the-page

Comment: Ryan was right about why it doesn't work, I guess because my css styles was override. So I decided to use '!important' to make sure that it won't be override. So instead of {margin: '15px'}, I used {margin: '15px !important'} and it worked! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing a similar problem and managed to solve it as below

```
root: {
        '&&': {
            width: "128px",
            height: "128px",
            margin: "8px",
        }
    },
```

I later also found an article about this [here](https://dev.to/magischerzwerg/double-ampersand-trick-in-sass-with-react-4khe).

Using the double ampersands "&&" increases/doubles up the specificity/priority.
So, for any class I wanted to override, I added the '&&' in my declared class.

This solved the problem for me without any noticeable downside but I don't know if this is actually a good practice. If anyone knows more about why not to use this, please let me know.