# Overriding material-ui styles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have found a number of posts regarding overriding styles but nothing quite like the issue I am having.  I am creating styled material-ui components and importing them into different parts of my application.  I want to be able to override some of my styling from the various parent components.

I have a button component:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonBlue: {
    background: "#09a1e2",
    border: "1px solid #09a1e2",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    color: "#ffffff",
    cursor: "pointer",
    fontSize: "1.25rem",
    padding: ".75rem 1.25rem .75rem 1.25rem",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      color: "#09a1e2"
    }
  },
  buttonWhite: {
    background: "#ffffff",
    border: "1px solid #666666",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    fontSize: "1rem",
    padding: ".5rem",
    width: "6rem",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#666666",
      color: "#ffffff"
    }
  }
});

const MediumButton = props => {
  const color = props.color;
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      {color === "blue" ? (
        <button className={classes.buttonBlue}>{props.buttonText}</button>
      ) : (
        <button className={classes.buttonWhite}>{props.buttonText}</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MediumButton;
```

which I will be importing into another component.  I want to override some of these styles on my new component but I can't quite figure out how.

Here is what I am trying:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { withContext } from "../../context/AppContext";
import MediumButton from "../components/MediumButton";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root : {
        display: "flex",
    },
    homeButton: {
        background: "white",
        border: "1px solid #09a1e2",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        color: "#09a1e2",
        cursor: "pointer",
        fontSize: "1.25rem",
        padding: ".5rem 3.25rem .5rem 3.25rem",
        textDecoration: 'none',
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            color: "#09a1e2"
        }

    }
});

const PageNotFound = () => {

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

      <MediumButton className={classes.homeButton} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default withContext(PageNotFound);
```

I'm not sure what I need to call to override the styles I set on my MediumButton component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you created *MediumButton*, you get to decide how to allow other components to override the default style.

***Option 1:*** 
 
Replace the entire default style 
is to send className prop from the father (just like you did), and in *MediumButton*, apply this styles if provided:

```
const MediumButton = props => {
  const { className, color } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      {color === "blue" ? (
        <button className={className || classes.buttonBlue}>{props.buttonText}</button>
      ) : (
        <button className={className || classes.buttonWhite}>{props.buttonText}</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

***Option 2:*** 
 
Replace only desired properties, and keep default styles. 
Send additonalStyles prop to MediumButton, and handle them in makeStyles:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  ........your other styles........
  additionalStyles: props => ({
    ...props
  }),
});

const MediumButton = props => {
  const { additionalStyles, color } = props;
  const classes = useStyles(additionalStyles);

  return (
    <div>
      {color === "blue" ? (
        <button className={`${classes.buttonBlue} ${classes.additionalStyles}`}>
          {props.buttonText}
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button className={`${classes.buttonWhite} ${classes.additionalStyles}`}>
          {props.buttonText}
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MediumButton;
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: This will work to completely override the styles on `MediumButton` but what if I want to keep all of the styles currently provided in the `MediumButton` component and just override the padding?

Answer (score 5):

If you allow a `className` property to be specified, you can apply that CSS class **in addition** to the CSS classes applied by your component (as opposed to **instead of** as shown in Ido's Option 1). If the overrides are created using `makeStyles`, then they will win over the default styling so long as the `makeStyles` call for the overrides is called **after** importing the component (see my related answers at the end for more details on this aspect -- with typical usage this will just work the way you would want).

Below is a working example of how this could work. Some additional aspects about my example version of `MediumButton` to make note of:

- Uses `children` rather than a `buttonText` prop
- Places common styles (those that should be the same regardless of the `color` prop`) into a separate CSS class (`mediumButton`) that is always applied
- Passes through to the `button` element any additional props not explicitly used in `MediumButton`. This makes it easy to pass in event handlers (e.g. `onClick`) or other properties supported by `button` (e.g. `disabled`) without needing to add extra code in `MediumButton` to handle those props.
- Uses clsx to conveniently combine multiple class names. clsx is used internally within Material-UI, so this won't add anything to your bundle size.

**MediumButton.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import clsx from "clsx";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  mediumButton: {
    borderRadius: "5px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    fontSize: "1.25rem",
    padding: ".75rem 1.25rem .75rem 1.25rem",
    margin: 8
  },
  buttonBlue: {
    background: "#09a1e2",
    border: "1px solid #09a1e2",
    color: "#ffffff",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      color: "#09a1e2"
    }
  },
  buttonWhite: {
    background: "#ffffff",
    border: "1px solid #666666",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#666666",
      color: "#ffffff"
    }
  }
});

const MediumButton = ({ className, children, color, ...other }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <button
      {...other}
      className={clsx(
        classes.mediumButton,
        {
          [classes.buttonBlue]: color === "blue",
          [classes.buttonWhite]: color !== "blue"
        },
        className
      )}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default MediumButton;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

import MediumButton from "./MediumButton";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  homeButton: {
    background: "white",
    color: "#09a1e2",
    border: "1px solid #09a1e2",
    padding: ".5rem 3.25rem .5rem 3.25rem",
    textDecoration: "none",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      color: "#09a1e2"
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MediumButton onClick={() => alert("You clicked me!")}>
        White Button
      </MediumButton>
      <MediumButton color="blue">Blue Button</MediumButton>
      <MediumButton className={classes.homeButton}>Home Button</MediumButton>
      <MediumButton className={classes.homeButton} color="blue">
        Blue Home Button
      </MediumButton>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit custom component style overrides]

Related answers for understanding which styles will win when layering multiple classes generated via `makeStyles`:

- [Material UI v4 makeStyles exported from a single file doesn't retain the styles on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929702/material-ui-v4-makestyles-exported-from-a-single-file-doesnt-retain-the-styles/56941531#56941531)
- [Internal implementation of "makeStyles" in React Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220059/internal-implementation-of-makestyles-in-react-material-ui/57226057#57226057)