# is it possible to override a theme override with component classes prop?

Tags: material-ui

I am wondering if there is a neat trick to use a component `classes` prop to override some CSS defined in a theme's overrides.

For instance :
If I want all `Button` components to have a different `font-size` than the default one. I can use the theme.overrides props to do so :

```js
// this works, all Buttons text is 1.1rem
let theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      label: {
        "&": {fontSize: "1.1rem"}
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Now if for some reason one of my button needs to have a different `font-size`, I was hoping using classes prop would do the job :

```js
const useClasses = makeStyles({
  smallerFontSize: {
    fontSize: "0.9rem"
  }
})
...
const classes = useClasses()
...
<Button 
  classes={{
    // unfortunately this doesn't work, theme overrides is taking precedence
    label: classes.smallerFontSize
  }}
>
  Some smaller text
</Button>
...
```

Since using `classes` prop allows us to target and override some component's CSS if default theme values have not been overridden, I find it confusing that theme overrides end up behaving somewhat differently and have a higher specificity than a one time rule.

I'd argue it kind of defeats the purpose of having a customisable theme.

But hopefully I'm missing something and your wisdom will help !

## UPDATE

My mistake was to export the created theme and the makeStyles hook from the same module file.

Doing that made Mui insert theme `<style>` after the hook `<style>`.
To fix the issue and be able to use classes component props as I wanted to :

- export theme and hooks from separate modules
- make sure theme module has no dependency on the module exporting the hook
- make sure when using `ThemeProvider` that it has no parent component importing the hook

I still don't quite understand why things worked before I added the overrides property on the theme object though.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/override-theme-overrides-wbe3p

Comment: Do you have your `makeStyles` call in a separate file such that you are importing the `useClasses` function?

Comment: @RyanCogswell: Yes I import my hook from a separate file. I have tried without importing and it works indeed ! I do not understand why this is different though ... And is there a way to define my hook in one place only and still be able to use it in other files ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material UI v4 makeStyles exported from a single file doesn't retain the styles on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929702/material-ui-v4-makestyles-exported-from-a-single-file-doesnt-retain-the-styles)

Comment: ... Yes, maybe ? My imports are ordered properly (completely accidentally ofc) and so I didn't really bump into the issue described. In fact, before I tried to override the theme, all was working as I'd expect. But there are plenty of leads for me to follow in your link. Thanks

Comment: So just to answer my own questions :

Comment: ... my issue was having createMuiTheme and makeStyles in the same file. makeStyles ended up inserting <style> before the theme styles. Exporting my theme and my hook from different files and ensuring ThemeProvider does not import the module containing the hook and is an ancestor to all components using the hook allowed me to use the classes property as described in my post.