# Material-UI styles overriding my styles cause of ordering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

Hello there fellow programmers.

I am currently experiencing an issue with my own styles created using `makeStyles(...)`. What's happening is; when I import my styles constant which is exported from another module, the `style` block is placed before the other `MUI` styles which causes mine to be overriden. I have not yet been able to find any solution to this what so ever and that is why I am here today, trying to figure out how I could possibly go my ways to fix this. [Here's an image that contains the order of the style blocks that is playing with my mind currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYx23.png).

**PLEASE NOTE:** The style block that's mine is the one with the data meta of `makeStyles`. Another thing is, I've attempted to use `StylesProvider`.

**IMPORTANT**: This only happens when uploaded. It works just fine on localhost, but this is the outcome of being uploaded to vercel.

Here's two examples of usages:

```js
import { Theme } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const DarkTheme = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  mdButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#404040"
  },
}));

export default DarkTheme;
```

```js
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import React from "react";
import DarkTheme from 'DarkTheme';

export default function Example() {
  const styles = DarkTheme();

  return (
    <Button className={styles.mdButton}>
      Example
    </Button>
  )
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please give example?

Comment: @VietDinh I edited with an example for you, I apologize for not providing it earlier; I am new to stackoverflow and forgot to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, f you have two CSS classes applied to the same element with the same degree of specificity, then the winner will be the CSS class that is defined last within the document (based on the order of the  **elements in the** , NOT the order of the class name strings in the class attribute of the element being styled). As: [Material UI v4 makeStyles exported from a single file doesn't retain the styles on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929702/material-ui-v4-makestyles-exported-from-a-single-file-doesnt-retain-the-styles)

So, you can change order of imports. Import Button before import style.
Let try with what is different from:

```
import React from "react";
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import DarkTheme from 'DarkTheme';
```

and

```
import React from "react";
import DarkTheme from 'DarkTheme';
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';
```

Comment: I'm aware of this. This is what I've got currently and it is still bugging out. A quick side note: it works fine on localhost, but not when uploaded, for example on vercel.

Comment: I see, you may have import Comopent before Style at anywhere call. I suggest you should move style to Component file or use other styling in react - material ui at: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#migration-for-material-ui-core-users

Comment: When it's uploaded, I guess it's in production-mode. If you have issues on builded app you can check this FAQ item: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-arent-my-components-rendering-correctly-in-production-builds

Answer (score -1):

`makeStyles` returns a function which must be called as a React hook. So please name it in consequence.

```
const useDarkTheme = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  mdButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#404040"
  },
}));

export default useDarkTheme;
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

If you don't want to use hooks you can check `withStyles` alternative: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

You can also check how CSS injection works in material-ui https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order (tl;dr: order of `makeStyles` calls matter).